# When I use UITableViewCell in order to customize each cell content, a screen layout is broken after scrolling in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to make a Customized Cell in UITableviewCell so that I can change the cell contents along with a parameter that is passed from ModelView. However, when I scroll, a layout is broken.

I tried to divide the code into 2 parts like below.

---

Declare Variables Part

---

Init Part contains Layout Definition

---

But if I divide into 2parts, I had not been able to change layouts along with variables because the Init Part run at first before 'Declare Variables Parts'. Furthermore, I tried to change layouts in 'Declare Variables Part', Layouts are broken. How should I code to pass a parameter to change Cell Contents? Below is part of my code. A layout of 'baseView' is gonna be broken.

```
[ViewModel]
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = items[indexPath.section]
    if let item = item as? AnniversaryViewModelContentsItem, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ANContentCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ANContentCell {
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.item = item.contents[indexPath.row]

        cell.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

[Cell: ANContentCell]
    // Declare Variable Part ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   ........
   var item: ANContent? {
        didSet {
            guard let item = item?.dataPerRow else {
                return
            }
            let graphArray = [graph00, graph01, graph02, graph03]

            if item.mode == 1 {
                baseView.anchor(
                    top: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                    leading: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                    bottom: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                    trailing: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                    padding: .init(top: 0, left:0, bottom:0, right:0), size: .init(width:0, height: item.hight )
                )
            } 

            for i in 0...(graphArray.count - 1){
                // Graph Anchor
                graphArray[i].anchor(
                    top: baseView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                    leading: baseView.leadingAnchor,
                    bottom: nil,
                    trailing: nil,
                    padding: .init(
                        top: item.top,
                        left: item.left,
                        bottom:0,
                        right:0
                    ),
                    size: .init(
                        width:item.width,
                        height: item.height
                    )
                )
                .........
            }
        }
    }

    private let baseView: UIView = {
        var baseView = UIView()
        baseView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return baseView
    }()

    var graph00: UIView = {
        let graph = UIView()
        return graph
    }()
    var graph01: UIView = {
        let graph = UIView()
        return graph
    }()
    var graph02: UIView = {
        let graph = UIView()
        return graph
    }()
    var graph03: UIView = {
        let graph = UIView()
        return graph
    }()

    // Init parts ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let graphArray = [graph00, graph01, graph02, graph03]

        // Add Object
        addSubview(baseView)
        for i in 0...(graphArray.count - 1){
            baseView.addSubview(graphArray[i])
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to set more of the code for the `item` `didSet`.

Comment: Okay. I added the code. But since the full code is a bunch of lines, I tried to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace::

```
var graph00: UIView = {
        let graph = UIView()
        return graph
}()
```

to:

```
var graph00 = UIView()
```

and add this code to your cell:

```
override func layoutIfNeeded() {
        self.subviews.forEach{$0.layoutIfNeeded()}
}
```

Comment: Mmm. I couldn't fix it.

Comment: if you will use this code:
var graph00: UIView = { return UIView()}()
it means every time when you will address to this variable you will create new object wich need add to cell and set new constraint
so when your set new model you need something like this:

`for i in 0...(graphArray.count - 1){              
 graphArray[i].anchor(
.........
 addSubview(graphArray[i])
.........
 }`

and remove views what you added before

Comment: I cannot move the setting anchors to 'init' because the anchors are related on variables. After getting variables I can set anchors so I cannot help setting the anchors in 'didset'.